# Highlighting bash code with knitr / rmarkdown

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to generate an HTML report using RStudio, R Markdown and knitr. In the report I would like to display some `bash` code. I do not want to run the code but I would like it to be highlighted.

It has been mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29223248/3017012) but the suggestion there doesn't work for me. Here's what I've tried so far:

````
---
title: "bash highlighting?"
output: html_document
---
```{r, engine = 'bash', eval = FALSE}
for foo in (ls bar)
do
  echo $foo
done
```

```{bash, eval = FALSE}
for foo in (ls bar)
do
  echo $foo
done
```
````

Neither of these give me highlighting in the HTML document. I know it's possible because I remember seeing it somewhere a week or so ago, but I can't find it anymore! Does anyone know how I can achieve it?

Thanks for reading,

Tom

Edit: I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697524/3017012), which suggests using the following code block in the .Rmd

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
});
</script>
```

This works for the bash code in the document but kills the highlighting for the R code!

```
## R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] formatR_1.2     tools_3.2.0     htmltools_0.2.6 yaml_2.1.13    
## [5] rmarkdown_0.5.1 knitr_1.10      stringr_0.6.2   digest_0.6.8   
## [9] evaluate_0.7
```

Comment: About [Yihui's examples on GitHub](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/), it would seem GitHub renders a [number of languages on its own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14697529/322912). What you could do is add your own [css file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14710957/322912). A third option would be to render the md file using e.g. pandoc.

Comment: To use pandoc, you would use `pandoc -s 027-engine-bash.md -t html -o bash.html`, but see [demos](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) for the myriad of options.

Comment: @Roman Yes, the code I added to my question uses a css file with `highlight.js`. It works pretty well but the R highlighting from `highlight.js` is not as nice as the highlighting from `RStudio`. What I need to do now is have the css file apply **only** to the non-R code chunks. Thanks again for the replies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default syntax highlighting theme does not work well for non-R code chunks, and you can use other themes, e.g. `pygments`

````
---
title: "Bash Highlighting"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: pygments
---

```{r, engine = 'bash', eval = FALSE}
for foo in (ls bar)
do
  echo $foo
done
```
````

Comment: Much easier than my answer. The [default theme](http://pandoc.org/README.html#general-writer-options) for `pandoc` **is** `pygments`, so I guess mine only worked through dumb luck.

Answer (score 3):

OK, figured it out thanks to the comments. It seems it's `RStudio` which is not playing nice with the highlighting. When I keep the intermediate markdown file as `in.md`:

````
---
title: "Bash Highlighting"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r, engine = 'bash', eval = FALSE}
for foo in (ls bar)
do
  echo $foo
done
```
````

then convert to html with `pandoc` using *e.g.* the CSS from BioConductor:

```
pandoc -s in.md \
    -c https://hedgehog.fhcrc.org/bioconductor/branches/RELEASE_3_1/madman/Rpacks/BiocStyle/inst/resources/html/bioconductor.css \
    -t html -o out.html
```

I get nice code highlighting for `R` and `bash`.

Thanks!