# Including floats (numbers with a decimal point) truncates the echoed bash code on Rmarkdown and knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am preparing a document in Rmarkdown (**knitr** version 1.15.1), to include codes in both bash and R (version 3.3.1).
For now, I'm only interested in printing out the code chunks, without evaluating them.
Everything works alright, except when I include a float (a number with a decimal point) in my bash chunks, which causes the echoed output to be truncated between the decimal points, like this:

````
```{bash echo = TRUE, eval=FALSE}
usearch -cluster_fast Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.fasta -id 0.95 -sort length \
-strand both -centroids Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.fasta \
-uc Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.clusters
```
````

Which produces the following html output:

```
usearch -cluster_fast Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.fasta -id 0.95.clusters
```

Basically truncating anything between the first `0.95` and the last one.
When I run the same code, as a `shell` chunk:

````
```{shell echo = TRUE, eval=FALSE}
usearch -cluster_fast Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.fasta -id 0.95 -sort length \
-strand both -centroids Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.fasta \
-uc Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.clusters
```
````

The output is as expected:

```
usearch -cluster_fast Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.fasta -id 0.95 -sort
length -strand both -centroids combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.fasta -uc 
Combined_P_maxima_assemblies.uclust0.95.clusters
```

Any idea why the code is being truncated and why there's a difference in the way the code is formatted?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be the same issue as https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/988

Comment: @Yihui Indeed. 
I found that using `highlight=pygments` in the YAML header solves it, as you've suggested in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914059/highlighting-bash-code-with-knitr-rmarkdown), but it still shouldn't behave this way.

Comment: Of course you are right. We should fix it but currently none of us have time. Sorry. I'll close this question and point to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29914059/559676 since they are caused by the same bug in rmarkdown. Thanks!